# MEAN: Jade Template problems with conditional Meta Tags

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, mean-stack

I have the following within my jade layout

```
doctype html
html
head
  meta(charset='utf-8')
  meta(http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible', content='IE=edge')
  meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
  if (pageDescription)
    meta(name='description', content=#{pageDescription})
  else
    meta(name='description', content='My description.')
```

However this produces a "Express 500 Syntax Error"

```
 7| | if (pageDescription)

 8| |

 9| meta(name='description', content=#{pageDescription})

 10| |

 11| | else

 12| |
```

Q) So how do I include conditional Meta tags in my templates Head ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#{pageDescription}` should only be used within a string, e.g. `"#{pageDescription}"`. You can do that, or else just pass the value directly:

```
meta(name='description', content=pageDescription)
```